# os.path.abspath('file1.txt') doesn't return the correct path

Tags: python, path

Say the path of the file 'file1.txt' is `/home/bentley4/Desktop/sc/file1.txt` 
Say my current working directory is `/home/bentley4`

```
import os
os.path.abspath('file1.txt')
```

returns `/home/bentley4/file1.txt`

```
os.path.exists('file1.txt')
```

returns `False`.
If I do

```
os.path.abspath('file_that_does_not_exist.txt')
```

It returns `/home/bentley4/file_that_does_not_exist.txt`
But again, this is not correct. The file does not even exist on my computer. Is there a way to get the correct absolute path from any directory I am currently working in? (aside from defining a new function)

So this only works when I am in the same directory as the existing file or in the directory one directory or more further from the path of the directory of that file?

Comment: That's quite curious, `os.path.abspath` should just work.  What does `os.getcwd()` return?  ... Oh, d'oh, hang on, you're saying that you're in `/home/bentley4` and you're expecting `os.path.abspath` to somehow find a file in a sub-directory thereof?  It doesn't do that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to find a file by name in any of the sub-directories of your current working directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`os.path.abspath(filename)` returns an absolute path as seen from your current working directory. It does no checking whether the file actually exists.

If you want the absolute path of `/home/bentley4/Desktop/sc/file1.txt` and you are in `/home/bentley4` you will have to use `os.path.abspath("Desktop/sc/file1.txt")`.

Comment: Well, it starts by checking `os.path.isabs()`.  But in this case, yes.

Answer (score 1):

abspath just builds a path, it doesn't check anything about files existing.

From the docs:

> On most platforms, this is equivalent to normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)).

Answer (score 0):

You will get the path with `os.path.abspath(__file__)`.

Comment: This does not work. os.path.abspath('__file1.txt__') behaves the same as os.path.abspath('file1.txt').

Comment: @Bentley4 os.path.abspath('file1.txt') will always behave the same as os.path.abspath('file1.txt') as long as Python lives...

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that previously the `cwd` was changed using the
os.chdir(another_path) and it's still loaded in the context of the current execution.
so the fix should be restore the original path after the use of the task in another_path has finish.
Example :

```
  original_path = os.getcwd()
  os.chdir(another_path) 
  # here perform some operation over another_path
  os.chdir(original_path ) # here is the restore of the original path
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same issue and I found this, hope it helps you:

os.path.join(root, f)