# Python: Missing directory when getting absolute path

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to read in a file that is user specified. If they only enter in the file name, I'd like to get the full absolute path for it so I can open it.

I've tried os.path.abspath(file_name), but its missing one level. I expect this:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/dir_with_main/dir4/file_name
```

but I get:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/dir_with_main/file_name
```

so my code throws an error when running main. I've looked at this solution: [os.path.abspath('file1.txt') doesn't return the correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025863/os-path-abspathfile1-txt-doesnt-return-the-correct-path), but the example is assuming that they know where to look (hardcoded path). The purpose of this script is to allow the user to place this file anywhere and still have access to it.

Thanks!

Comment: If the file could be anywhere, and the user enters only a filename, *you cannot locate the file* - there simply isn't enough information.  Well, I suppose you could search the entire filesystem, but that's slow, and may find some other file that coincidentally has the same name.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for the feedback! I'll change my approach then. Do you know why os.path.abspath is omitting the dir4 in the example?

Comment: `os.path.abspath()`, given only a filename, just tacks the current directory in front of that filename.  The results have ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to do with whether or not the resulting pathname refers to an existing file.